# Selecting all the child elements using the XPath to display in Selenium, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How to select all the child elements of a particular parent element and display it on a loop?

Documentation should I refer to understand which methods to use?
Thanks.

```
<div class="Pitch-sc-1mctasb-0 mPWDj"><div class="Pitch__ElementRow-sc-1mctasb-1 Pitch__PitchRow-sc-1mctasb-2 bjBvcU"><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Goalkeeper" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">GKP</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0_1-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Goalkeeper" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">GKP</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"></div></div><div class="Pitch__ElementRow-sc-1mctasb-1 Pitch__PitchRow-sc-1mctasb-2 bjBvcU"><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Defender" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">DEF</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Defender" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">DEF</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Defender" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">DEF</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Defender" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">DEF</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Defender" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">DEF</span></abbr></div></button></div></div><div class="Pitch__ElementRow-sc-1mctasb-1 Pitch__PitchRow-sc-1mctasb-2 bjBvcU"><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Midfielder" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">MID</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Midfielder" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">MID</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Midfielder" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">MID</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Midfielder" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">MID</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Midfielder" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">MID</span></abbr></div></button></div></div><div class="Pitch__ElementRow-sc-1mctasb-1 Pitch__PitchRow-sc-1mctasb-2 bjBvcU"><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Forward" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">FWD</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Forward" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">FWD</span></abbr></div></button></div><div class="Pitch__PitchUnit-sc-1mctasb-3 jDkpw"><button class="PitchPlaceholder__StyledPlaceholder-sc-1jzdtaz-0 jEoHLb"><picture><source type="image/webp" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.webp 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.webp 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.webp 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px"><img src="/dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png" srcset="
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-66.png 66w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-110.png 110w,
        /dist/img/shirts/standard/shirt_0-220.png 220w
        " sizes="(min-width: 1024px) 55px, (min-width: 610px) 44px, 33px" alt="" class="Shirt__StyledShirt-k5q8zl-0 hoGPkp"></picture><div data-testid="title" class="PitchPlaceholder__Title-sc-1jzdtaz-1 gAiHPL">Add <abbr title="Forward" class="PitchPlaceholder__Abbr-sc-1jzdtaz-2 ffGrvw"><span class="PitchPlaceholder__Span-sc-1jzdtaz-3 cVbLKM">FWD</span></abbr></div></button></div></div></div>
```

The main div class: Pitch-sc-1mctasb-0 mPWDj, has 4 div child elements, and under those child elements there are further child elements. I want to get the XPATH seperately and display them under the correct div parent.

Comment: Please post the html code instead of screenshot

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `find_elements()` to get the list of elements.

Note: while iterating through a list of elements you night get `StaleElementReferenceException` so you must handle the exception.

For your case use:

```
lst_of_el = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div[class^='Pitch-sc'] div")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebElement.<Locator Strategy>("<Locator>")` method to get all the child element. Like for shared HTML if you do:

```
parent = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Pitch-sc-1mctasb-0 mPWDj']") #As class has compound string css selector is failing, used xpath
children = parent.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")
print(len(children))
```

As there are total 36 divs inside div with class name `Pitch-sc-1mctasb-0 mPWDj. It will print 36.

If you want to filter only selective child divs, modify your locator accordingly.Like below will only select 15 divs with data-testid as title:

```
parent = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Pitch-sc-1mctasb-0 mPWDj']")
children = parent.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='title']")
print(len(children))
```

Comment: Thanks fr the reply. But with that it doesnt find or recognizes the element. It gives a NoSuchElementException. How do I work around that?

Comment: Can you copy your HTML here instead of image? Then it will be easy for me to replicate.

Comment: I have added it to the main question. Also, below the code, I have explained a bit what i want. Thanks.

Comment: Check the updated answer I have given 2 examples , i hope it will clarify your doubts now

Comment: def picking_players(self):              
        parent = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Pitch-sc-1mctasb-0 mPWDj']")
        childrenElements = parent.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='title']")        
        
        for children in childrenElements:
            children.click()
            while TRUE:
                if self.getFundsRemaining()<100:
                    print("Money Left")     
                else:
                    break;
            sleep(2)

Comment: NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class='Pitch-sc-1mctasb-0 mPWDj']"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.83)

Comment: Looks like you need to use some wait for page to load. You can use time.sleep(8) or implicit wait or explicit wait.